# return hmac key in javascript

Tags: javascript, hmac

From my api provider i have a code thats suposed to generate a hmac key.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>var BuckarooHmac = (function () {
    var self = {};

    function getEncodedContent(content) {
        if (content) {
            var md5 = CryptoJS.MD5(content);
            var base64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(md5);
            return base64;
        }

        return content;
    }

    function getHash(websiteKey, secretKey, httpMethod, nonce, timeStamp, requestUri, content) {
        var encodedContent = getEncodedContent(content);

        var rawData = websiteKey + httpMethod + requestUri + timeStamp + nonce + encodedContent;
        var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(rawData, secretKey);
        var hashInBase64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);

        return hashInBase64;
    }

    function getTimeStamp() {
        return Math.floor((new Date).getTime() / 1000);
    }

    function getNonce() {
        var text = "";
        var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
        for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
        }
        return text;
    }

    self.GetAuthHeader = function (requestUri, websiteKey, secretKey, content, httpMethod) {
        var nonce = getNonce();
        var timeStamp = getTimeStamp();
        content = content ? content : "";
        var url = encodeURIComponent(requestUri).toLowerCase();
        return "hmac " + websiteKey + ":" + getHash(websiteKey, secretKey, httpMethod, nonce, timeStamp, url, content) + ":" + nonce + ":" + timeStamp;
    }
    return self;
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = self.GetAuthHeader();
}());

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm not used to javascript. I'm trying to figure out how to print the generated key on my screen. I tried this :

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = self.GetAuthHeader();
```

I know i must be doing this wrong. I just need a push in the right direction now. Anyone that could help me ?

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using the built in `crypto.subtle` in browsers? It's [pretty straightforward](https://github.com/diafygi/webcrypto-examples#hmac) to get an hmac if you already know the base concepts.

Comment: Where are you trying that line of code?  If it's outside that enclosed function scope then there is no `self` variable, but there is `BuckarooHmac.GetAuthHeader()`.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I didnt type this code . Its already created. I'm just trying to get the results to show.

Comment: @David there is a self variable. And i'm trying that line of code right under return self;

Comment: @Kevin: Instead of merely describing what you've tried, demonstrate it in the code in the question.

Comment: @David i added what i've tried to the main code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re trying to perform an action *after* the function’s return statement.  That code will never be reached because the function has returned.

Instead, do it before:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = self.GetAuthHeader();
return self;
```

Or, even better, if this code is provided by a vendor then you probably shouldn’t edit it.  Updates would remove your edits, and vendor support would be compromised.  Instead, perform your action outside the code entirely:

```
var BuckarooHmac = (function () {
    // vendor code
}());

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = BuckarooHmac.GetAuthHeader();
```